# Использование MessageBox.Show

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо отловить результат нажатия на кнопку на messagebox и в зависимости от выбранного варианта далее продолжить. Вот мой код:

```
MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Как проверить какой вариант ответа был выбран?

Comment: Метод `Show` возвращает `DialogResult`. [Примеры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(...);
switch (result)
{
    case DialogResult.OK:
    ...
    break;
    case DialogResult.Cancel:
    ...
    break;
}
```